# Overfull hbox in TOC caused by bold text

Tags: memoir

I'm writing my dissertation in latex using overleaf. I'm having a problem where the use of bold text in the ucbthesis class toc seems to be creating an overfull hbox when the bibliography is on a page with a page number >99

code is approximately:

```
\documentclass[draft]{ucbthesis}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,articletitle=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{init = strict}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\usepackage{rotating} % provides sidewaystable and sidewaysfigure
\usepackage{graphicx}

\addtolength{\abovecaptionskip}{\baselineskip}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Jibberish}

\bibliography{references}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}

\hyphenation{mar-gin-al-ia}
\hyphenation{bra-va-do}

\include{compound-list}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables

\end{frontmatter}

\pagestyle{headings}

%\include{chap1}
%\include{chap2}
%\include{chap3}
\include{chap4}
%\include{chap5}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and it's causing this:

[image: toc overfull hbox]

Answer (score 2):

The `ucbthesis` class is a modified version of the standard LaTeX `memoir`
class that is accepted for use with University of California, Berkeley,
Ph.D. dissertations and Master’s theses.

The `memoir` draft option marks any overfull lines with black rectangles, otherwise the appearance
is the same as for a final document.

When the page number has three  digits a warning appears: `Overfull \hbox (2.03766pt too wide)` and the black box as shown:

[image: a]

This can be corrected using

`\cftlocalchange{toc}{⟨pnumwidth⟩}{⟨tocrmarg⟩}`

to make page number width big enough  and change the margin (`memman.pdf` page #160}

If necessary `\cftlocalchange{toc}{1.55em}{2.55em}` will  return to the normal settings.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[draft]{ucbthesis}

\usepackage{showframe}% ONLY to show margins <<<<<
\begin{document}
    
    \frontmatter
    \cftlocalchange{toc}{3.55em}{5.55em}% added <<<<<<<
    
    \tableofcontents    
    \mainmatter
    
    \setcounter{page}{90}
    \chapter{One}
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{137}
\chapter{Two}   

\end{document}
```

You should refer this problem to the maintainers of the `ucbthesis` class.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, the width of the box containing the page numbers is given by `\@pnumwidth`. When macro `\cftlocalchange` is not available, this can be changed by writing in the preamble of the document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{2.55em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{3.55em}
\makeatother
```

It is important that `\@tocrmarg > \@pnumwidth`; typically, `\@tocrmag = \@pnumwidth + 1em`